# How to make query statement case in variable SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, case

This works:

```
select 
    idpelamar,
    case 
       when jk = 'L' then 'Laki' 
       when jk = 'P' then 'Perem' 
    end as XJENIS
from tblpelamar
```

How to apply the `case` statement to initialize a variable?

Like this below:

```
declare @jenis nvarchar(1)
declare @perintah nvarchar(100)
set @jenis = 'L'

set @perintah = 'case when jk=@jenis then Laki when jk=@jenis then Prem end as XJENIS'

select 
    idpelamar,
    +@perintah
from tblpelamar
```

Comment: Could you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64616978/edit) some sample data and the expected result to your question please?

Comment: `CASE` **Expression**. SQL Server does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
declare @jenis1 as nvarchar(1) = 'L';
declare @jenis2 as nvarchar(1) = 'P';

select idpelamar,
       case jk
         when @jenis1 then 'Laki'
         when @jenis2 then 'Prem'
       end as XJENIS
from tblpelamar;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63a7d2c00436103543985337ab95f819)